# Android Animation smooth on emulator but not so smooth on the device! Why?

Tags: android, animation, sdk, smoothing

I've created an image button which has a shake animation(much like I phone on click)!.

All are good on emulator and logcat but, when I try to click the image button on the real device the animation looks like 2 frame video, not smooth at all!

Also the hardware Accelerated, is set to true in Android manifest file and the target SDK is set to 19.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It seems that your device is occupied by another task. Did you try to stop other apps or just reboot your device?

Comment: I've rebooted the device same thing!